# Farm Based Custom Timer Job Feature

Tags: 2007, event-handlers, timer-jobs, farm

I am trying to create a custom timer job where feature is farm scoped and will run on a farm level, I am not able to find any decent tutorial that tells how to create a farm based custom timer job feature.

I am able to look at few Web Application based custom timer job features, but they look different, e.g. this one..

[Web Application based Custom Timer Job Feature](http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/articles/CreatingCustomSharePointTimerJobs.aspx)

In following Piece of code, what should I put instead of web application as I want my feature to run on a farm not a web application :S

```
public TaskLoggerJob (string jobName, SPWebApplication webApplication)
  : base (jobName, webApplication, null, SPJobLockType.ContentDatabase) {
  this.Title = "Task Logger";
}
```

there is another constructor I find but dunno how to use it

[MSDN constructors I can use](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spjobdefinition.spjobdefinition.aspx)

What is Service and which one can I use ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no farm level timer job. A custom timer job will only be installed on Web application/Site Collection level. So it's impossible to deploy a custom timer job definition on farm level.

**Edit**: But, you can have a custom timer job code which is deployed to the farm but it is installed/register on a Web Application level.